# How to register a path reference/map for typescript compiler?

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs

I've decided to use my own absolute paths in angular2 in order to avoid this kind of path references:

`import someThing from "../../../../../somePath"`

I'm using systemjs. My own *mappings* declared at **systemjs.config.js**:

```
var map = {
    ....
    "@services": "app/services",
    "@pipes":    "app/pipes"
};
```

Everything works fine on the browser, without errors. The files are being imported correctly. But **typescript compiler** throws some errors:

> error TS2307: Cannot find module '@services/SomeService.service'.

But, off course, imports like `@angular/core` work fine, so it's possible to solve this.

### What is the way to indicate typescript compilers these paths are being mapped?

Comment: Follow this thread, I think it will be possible to do that soon https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular2-seed-advanced/issues/180

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
"paths": {
            "baseUrl": "./",
            "*": [
                "app/*",
                "app/main/*"
            ]
      }
```

The above should be in `tsconfig.json`